# How to setup schedular/Cron jobs on AWS Env with Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

Currently i am using AWS Elastic beanstalk for web application deployment. I am using rails framework for backend and mysql(RDS) for database. Now i need to automate my background tasks(e.g. sending bulk emails,create reports etc.). So what would be best possible way to run cronjobs(background task).

I couldn't find any suitable example in Stack Overflow as well as google.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of article about setup cron job. I am sharing one of best cronjob setup tutorial below.

[Click Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-on-a-vps)

Answer (score 1):

There are so many options available to achieve mentioned target.If we take the specific example of sending an email and generating reports. I would suggest giving a try to [Whenever Gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever). You can schedule your rake task to run at specific intervals. I am sure it will best suit to your requirement,If not or you want to build more robust and event based cron jobs then check out [Aws Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) and [step functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) along with [Cloud Watch Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) events.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using delayed_job gem. It's easy to start with and can manage background workers easily. For more information on other background jobs, follow below link
https://www.sitepoint.com/comparing-background-processing-libraries-sidekiq/